# Iterate through a binary search tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I want to go through every item in a dictionary in Java. To clarify what I want to do, this is the C# code:

```
Dictionary<string, Label> LableList = new Dictionary<string, Label>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Label> z in LabelList) { … }
```

Comment: What is `BinarySearchTreeDictionary`? What is its `iterator` method?

Comment: What *is* `BinarySearchTreeDictionary`?  Is it backed by a `Map`?

Comment: Please add the error and stacktrace you are getting

Comment: Also, even without knowing what a `BinarySearchTreeDictionary` is, you probably don't want to be calling `.next()` twice per iteration. More related: I'd *imagine* that `iterator()` is returning an iterator into either a full entry set, or just the value list (since it is obviously not returning a direct iterator for the key set); so you'll need to check the documentation / methods of `BinarySearchTreeDictionary` and use the correct methods appropriately (whatever they are).

Comment: //BinarySearchDictionary is my class name
//  from a class that implements the Comparable interface.
public class BinarySearchTreeDictionary<K extends Comparable<K>,V> implements Iterable<BinarySearchTreeDictionary.BSTNode<K, V>>
{

Comment: your main() is irrelevant since you haven't posted the full BinarySearchTreeDictionary class. It's impossible to help you like that.

Comment: @user2803053 Please accept an answer below by clicking on the check mark against an answer or modify your question to get more satisfactory answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
temp += ("<" + it.next() + ", " + bstd.getValue(it.next()) + ">");
```

is calling `next` twice per `hasNext()`.  Store the next value in a local variable.

```
Object current = it.next();
temp += ("<" + current + ", " + bstd.getValue(current) + ">");
```

Answer (score 0):

To iterate without map iterator:

```
 for(Type t : map.values().toArray(new Type[map.size()])) {
      //values
 }
```

Although I haven't used this in a while, there's probably a  cleaner way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is the [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) or the [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) to implement a dictionary in Java. The HashMap class uses hashing to maintain the dictionary while TreeMap uses a Red Black Tree(a variant of the BST) to maintain the dictionary.

Moreover, if the mapping is from a String to a class Label, then can use the following code. You will also have to import java.util.* and declare the Label class separately for the code to run successfully.

```
    TreeMap<String, Label> map = new TreeMap<String, Label>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Label> entry : map.entrySet()){
         System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
    }
```